# Add element to arraylist inside haspmap in java 1.4

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java1.4

I need to work in java 1.4 which doesn't support generics. This is the code I wrote in java 8

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();
m.put("a", vals);
m.get("a").add(var_name);
```

After reading jdk 1.4 docs, I managed to get write the below code but how do I add an element to ArrayList inside the map? I don't want to add the values to ArrayList first and then add the ArrayList to map.

```
LinkedHashMap m = new LinkedHashMap();
ArrayList vals = new ArrayList();
m.put("a", vals);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast beforehand

```
((ArrayList)m.get("a")).add(var_name);
```

Of course, if you want to use that value later, you'd have to cast that as well.

Comment: It worked but couldn't find info about this anywhere else. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

You can even do this if you are using a higher version of java

```
 m.put("a", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one")));
 m.get("a").add("two");
```

http://ideone.com/IGnHF4

Comment: The op refers to a  java 1.4 requirement. Generics don't exist in Java 1.4.

Comment: I didn't  downvote but `new ArrayList<String>` will still not compile.

Comment: @davidxxx It works fine Are you sure ? find the updated example in the question http://ideone.com/IGnHF4

Comment: I donot understand how you said it wont compile, also to tghe downvoter please comment on the same

Comment: It won't compile, because Java 1.4 doesn't have generics, so `new ArrayList<String>()` is a syntax error in that Java version.

Comment: Do you see the update i posted in the second comment if we use a higher version of java this is not just not done. Hope u delete the comment

Comment: And that doesn't answer the question, because the OP specifically asks for Java 1.4, and he already shows a very similar solution that works in Java 8 in the question itself.